# Why does Payne take Annie hostage?

Tags: plot-explanation, speed

In *Speed* why does Payne take Annie hostage?

He saw the recording had been looped, and so he knew Jack and the others were probably off the bus at that point, or that the police were working on a plan of some kind. He can even see the police in the windows across the street. He must've known that, even though he saw them drop the money in the garbage can, it was probably rigged with a tracker, the paint bomb, or something. He knew they weren't just going to **give** him all that money.

So why bother to take Annie as a hostage at all?

If he's that hellbent on getting the cash, even with the possibility of a tracking device, why not just slip down into the subway (at this point, the police don't know about the hole in the sidewalk) and run off with the money?

Answer (score 4):

Because Payne's main goal was pain (the pun was probably intended). Payne wanted revenge above all. First (of four), it started with giving pain; making those who wronged him get their comeuppance. They would be embarrassed, exposed, and cause the loss of cash.

Second, Payne knew that they would identify him. So he turned it into part of his plan. His gift watch was the symbol of his undervalued retirement. He made it part of the explosive mechanism. He also booby trapped his house.

Third, Payne had it in for Jack Traven because he had failed at his hands before. Payne noticed the growing relationship Jack had with Annie. So when his plan went up in smoke, he knew that kidnapping Annie would bring Jack. And he had to get Jack.

Fourth, his plan would end with his retirement cash that "he had earned".